# Eclipse webdriver error: ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm getting this error "`ClassNotFoundException`" when I try to execute this line of code:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Now, here is the thing. This code was running perfectly fine from the default Eclipse workspace (username/workspace). What I am trying to do is now move my `*.java` files to a new workspace. And now I'm having this problem.

I've put all of my jar files into one folder and have added them to my package. I have `selenium-java-xxx.jar` and `selenium-server-standalone-xxx.jar` files in this new jar folder.

I can switch back to my old workspace and the file runs perfectly fine (firefox loads up fine and executes my selenium java code).

But when I switch to my new workspace, I get the error on that line of code.

I'm not sure where to look to try and fix this error?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you added these jar files in build path?

Comment: Try doing a  Project->Clean.

Comment: Project->Clean worked...thanks...